# Methods of ensuring a function is called only once inside object literal

Tags: javascript

There are lots of methods on SO for ensuring a function is only called once, but I have found none that address the following context and goals.
The context is a function within an object literal, and the goal is to put this utility onto `Function.prototype`, or to make it less verbose somehow.
Currently I am doing this:

```
var HugeLiteral={
  subComponent:{
    _name:'subComponent'
    ,_privateFnsEtc:function(){
    }
    ,_init:function(){
      // start of thing I would like to "Macro-ize"
      if (arguments.callee.initialized) {console.error('already initialized');return;}
      arguments.callee.initialized=true;
      // End
      //
      // I would like to say something like
      if (!arguments.callee._proceed()) {return;}// _proceed logs the error
      //
      // or alternatively
      globalRunOnceCheckFn();// uses stack to get this function and do a throw
      // or 
      maybeWrapCallingFunction(this);
      // 
      codeToExecuteOnceHere();
      //
      // or this method which would tend to lock me into a single return point
      this._init=this._init.guardFnOnFunctionPrototype;
    }
  }
  ,_init:function(){
    // Here I could walk HugeLiteral and do whatever, 
    // but I am not sure I like wrapping the _inits.
  }
};
```

My main requirement is that the way of doing this must operate from inside the function, I know I could wrap the function externally to make it run once.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a boolean property to the object that's true if the function was already called -> `if (this.called) return;`

Comment: a little off topic but in `strict` mode you can't use `arguments.callee` and you can't have two properties of the same name, ie  `_init`. It's bad practice.

Comment: @Moogs The `_inits` are on different objects, surely that isn't bad practice or is it? Thanks for the tip on `strict`.

Comment: @MarkRobbins oh my mistake didn't see that they were nested.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        this.foo = function(){};
        return 'once';
    }
};

console.log(obj.foo()); // 'once'
console.log(obj.foo()); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IIFE closure to store a variable that keeps track of whether it's already been run:

```
var obj = {
    myFunc: (function() {
        var alreadyRun = false;
        return function(arg1, arg2) {
            if (!alreadyRun) {
                alreadyRun = true;
                // rest of your code here
            }
        };
    })();
};
```

Or, you can make a helper function to make the usage cleaner and make it easier to resuse this concept in multiple places:

```
// helper function that returns a function stub that can only be called once
function allowRunOnce(fn) {
    var alreadyRun = false;
    return function() {
        if (!alreadyRun) {
            alreadyRun = true;
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}

var obj = {
    myFunc: allowRunOnce(function(arg1, arg2) {
        // code here for a method that can only be called once
    });
};
```